# How to implement a custom validator with Angular2 in Dart?

Tags: dart, angular

My code:

```
<input #rtc="ngForm" 
       type="number" 
       min="1" 
       max="43200" 
       style="text-align: center" 
       [(ngModel)]="device.rtc" 
       ngControl="rtc" 
       required>
```

The `ngControl` does not track the number type input valid status. How to implement a validator for the input myself?

Here is my test code:

Dart:

```
class MyComponent 
{
    Control ctrlRtc = new Control('test', rtcValidator);

    static Map<String, bool> rtcValidator(Control control)
    {
        print(111); 
    } 
}
```

HTML template:

```
<input 
    #deviceRtc="ngForm"
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="43200"
    style="text-align: center" 
    [(ngModel)]="device.rtc"
    ngControl="ctrlRtc" <!-- also tried 'rtc'-->
>
```

The "111" is never shown in the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({  
  'rtc':  ['', MyValidator.validate]  
});


class MyValidator {
  static Map<String, bool> validate(Control control) {
    if(control.value !...) {
      return {'someErrorKey': true};
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you explain more details of your code?
i am fresh man with both dart and angular...
1)what the 'this' mean ? the context is component code?
2)what is the fb ?

Comment: Not sure what to explain. A validator is passed to the `rtc` control `['', MyValidator.validate]`. `''`, is the initial value, the 2nd argument is a single validator or a list of validators if you want to apply more than one. The validator itself is just a function which is called by Angular and where the `Control` is passed. If the value doesn't fulfill some criteria return a `Map` with an error key and an error value (not sure what the value is for). From the docs it doesn't seem seem it needs to be `bool`.

Comment: `class MyComponent 
{ 
  Control ctrlRtc1 = new Control(['test', rtcValidator]); 
 
  static Map<String, bool> rtcValidator(Control control) { 
    print(111); 
  } 
}` 

this is my test code, but the print(111) never showed...

Comment: Seems the comment is not complete yet. Please edit your question and put the code there. Code in comments is very hard to read. There is an `edit` link just below the [ [tag:dart] ] [ [tag:angular2] ] tags (to the bottom-left) of your question..

Comment: `Control ctrlRtc = new Control(['test', rtcValidator]);` should be instead `Control ctrlRtc = new Control('test', rtcValidator);` without the `[]` otherwise `['test', rtcValidator]` is used as the initial value of the control.

Comment: i have modified the code, but my rtcValidator just run once when program bootstrap, it seems the Control which created by hand not bind to the html element #deviceRtc

Comment: See for an example https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/dart_playground/blob/025db6579e41d30d9be892bdffeee95e89e3d39a/angular2/forms_and_validation_in_angular_2/lib/app_element.dart#L101-L101

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [`ngFormControl`](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.common/NgFormControl-class) instead of `ngControl`. You don't need the `#deviceRtc` spy.

```
<input 
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="43200"
    style="text-align: center" 
    [(ngModel)]="device.rtc"
    [ngFormControl]="ctrlRtc">
```

Then you will see that your `rtcValidator(...)` is called every time the input changes. I won't bother explaining the return type of the validator function, because Günter already demonstrated that in his answer.

I didn't try running your example, but I do have [a working example](https://github.com/mehaase/ng2_quickstart/blob/form/lib/app_component.dart) you can try.

Comment: I followed the linked example and got validation working perfectly